# Anything wrong with multi dispatch Redux Thunk or setState that is blocking component update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting this weird error, Warning: Cannot update a component (`Connect(Cart)`) while rendering a different component (`Cart`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Cart`. I can't figure where is the actual problem, in Cart.js or cartActions.js? cartActions.js used Redux Thunk, sometimes multi dispacth in one action creator. Thanks in advance.

Cart.js,

```
import { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar';
import { Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, Alert, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect }from 'react-redux';
import { getCart, deleteFromCart } from '../actions/cartActions';
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import { checkout } from '../actions/orderActions';

class Cart extends Component {
    /*state = {
        loaded: false
    }*/

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false
        }
    }

    //this.state.loaded = false;

    static propTypes = {
        getCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        addToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteFromCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        cart: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        checkout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    getCartItems = async (id) => {
        await this.props.getCart(id);
        //this.state.loaded = true;
        this.setState({
            loaded:  true
        });
    }

    onDeleteFromCart = (id, itemId) => {
        this.props.deleteFromCart(id, itemId);
    }

    render() {
        const user = this.props.user;
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated && !this.props.cart.loading && !this.state.loaded) {
            this.getCartItems(user._id);
        }

        //Why bind this with multiple things below?
        //<Button color="danger" onClick={this.onDeleteFromCart.bind(this, user._id, item.productId)}>Delete</Button>
        return (
            <div>
                <AppNavbar />
                {this.props.isAuthenticated ?
                    <Fragment>
                        {this.props.cart.cart ? null :
                            <Alert color="info" className="text-center">Your cart is empty!</Alert>
                        }
                    </Fragment>
                    : <Alert color="danger" className="text-center">Login to View!</Alert>
                }
                {this.props.isAuthenticated && !this.props.cart.loading && this.state.loaded && this.props.cart.cart ?
                    <Container>
                        <div className="row">
                            {this.props.cart.cart.items.map(item => (
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <Card>
                                        <CardBody>
                                            <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.name}</CardTitle>
                                            <CardSubtitle tag="h6">USD {item.price}</CardSubtitle>
                                            <CardText>Quantity - {item.quantity}</CardText>
                                            <Button color="danger" onClick={this.onDeleteFromCart.bind(this, user._id, item.productId)}>Delete</Button>
                                        </CardBody>
                                    </Card>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <CardTitle  tag="h5">Total Cost = USD {this.props.cart.cart.bill}</CardTitle>
                                    <Checkout 
                                        user={user._id} 
                                        amount={this.props.cart.cart.bill}
                                        checkout={this.props.checkout}
                                    />
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </Container>
                    : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cart: state.cart,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    user: state.auth.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCart, deleteFromCart, checkout})(Cart);
```

cartActions.js,

```
//import axios from "axios";
import axios from "../http-common";
import { GET_CART, ADD_TO_CART, DELETE_FROM_CART, CART_LOADING } from "./types";
import { returnErrors } from './errorActions';

export const getCart = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setCartLoading());
    axios.get(`/api/cart/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_CART,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
        });
}

export const addToCart = (id, productId, quantity) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`/api/cart/${id}`, {productId, quantity})
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_TO_CART,
            payload: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
}

//My addition for testing below,
/*export const updateCart = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.put(`/api/cart/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_CART,
            payload: Promise.all([id, res.data])
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
}*/

export const deleteFromCart = (userId, itemId) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.delete(`/api/cart/${userId}/${itemId}`)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_FROM_CART,
            payload: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
}

export const setCartLoading = () => {
    return {
        type: CART_LOADING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The code is dispatching the `getCart` action and enqueuing a state update in the `render` method. Both are ***unintentional*** side-effects.

```
class Cart extends Component {
  ...

  getCartItems = async (id) => {
    await this.props.getCart(id);    // <-- unintentional side-effect
    this.setState({ loaded: true }); // <-- unintentional side-effect
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.props.user;
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated &&
      !this.props.cart.loading &&
      !this.state.loaded
    ) {
      this.getCartItems(user._id);
    }

    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cart: state.cart,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  user: state.auth.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getCart, deleteFromCart, checkout }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

## Solution

React render functions are to be considered ***pure synchronous*** functions. Use the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods to issue these as ***intentional*** side-effects.

Example:

```
class Cart extends Component {
  ...

  getCartItems = async () => {
    const { cart, getCart, isAuthenticated, user } = this.props;
    const { loaded } = this.state;

    if (isAuthenticated && !cart.loading && !loaded) {
      await getCart(user.id);
      this.setState({ loaded: true });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCartItems();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getCartItems();
  }

  render() {
    // no unintentional side-effects :)

    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cart: state.cart,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  user: state.auth.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getCart, deleteFromCart, checkout }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew Reese for your answer. But I am confused about Intentional and Unintentional (in terms of side effects). If you kindly explain about them or point me to an article where they are explained in detail that will be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @ZonaedHasan Id' suggest reviewing the `React-StrictMode` documentation, see [Detecting Unexpected Side-Effects](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), and [React Component - render](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) docs. These cover the purpose of `render` being a pure function and a bit of the relationship to unintentional side-effects. The React Function component equivalent of these lifecycle methods is `useEffect`, e.g. "use a *side-effect*".